# how to call onclick function on name attribute of an input element by using a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

I have the following HTML markup:

```
<select class="form-control travel_mode" name="travel_request[travel_stays_attributes][0][travel_mode]" style="width: 139px;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option disabled="true" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Flight</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control travel_mode" name="travel_request[travel_stays_attributes][1448001168204][travel_mode]" style="width: 139px;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option disabled="true" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Flight</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control travel_mode" name="travel_request[travel_stays_attributes][1448002208899][travel_mode]" style="width: 139px;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option disabled="true" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Flight</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control travel_mode" name="travel_request[travel_stays_attributes][1448002215357][travel_mode]" style="width: 139px;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option disabled="true" selected="selected">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Flight</option>
</select>
```

I want to call `onclick` or `onchange` function on these elements on the name attributes, by writing a regular expression so that I can call a single JS function upon the click of any of the above dropdowns. How can I write the regular expression for the above markup?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a regular expression; all the elements have a `class` on them, so you can use that:

```
$('select.form-control').change(function() {
    console.log('I changed value...');
});
```

If you want to make it more specific to these elements, you could use the `name` attribute in an [attribute starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector) selector:

```
$('select[name^="travel_request[travel_stays_attributes]"]').change(function() {
    console.log('I changed value...');
});
```

Comment: thanks. but i have some other dropdowns also with the same class. i do not want to call the function on those elements.

Comment: but where to write the regular expression? that matches every random number of any length? (like 1448002208899)

Comment: why because i am having the names to the inputs like these, travel_request[travel_stays_attributes][1448002208899][travel_mode] , travel_request[travel_stays_attributes][1448002208899][travel_range],travel_request[travel_stays_attributes][1448002208899][city] .  so i want use a regular expression in the middle of the name.

Comment: But ***why***? Using a Regex in a selector is both redundant and slow. If you want to retrieve the long number in the `name` attribute, add it as a `data-*` property and retrieve it in the click handler.

Comment: actually these markup iam not generating manually these attributes are  generated by the ruby on rails framework. and the framework is internally using. when i use the nested form in rails.